# pyUnit unit testing for Magento a good idea?

Tags: python, unit-testing, magento, continuous-integration, python-unittest

Today it was suggested to me to use PyUnit with our Magento modules because of its request and response objects. Is there any advantage to using an xUnit testing framework?

We would be running Hudson as the CI with Maven along with some PHPUnit and Selenium Tests. I am currently using the Request and Response controllers from Zend Framework in PHPUnit.

Comment: Don't ask for 'opinions', ask for 'experience'.

Answer (score 3):

Magento unit-testing framework: https://github.com/IvanChepurnyi/EcomDev_PHPUnit

Comment: Interesting.. I might steal an idea of two from them like the fact that they packaged it up in a module.  I think I like using Zend's Test Request and Response Controllers though rather than their custom watered down controllers.